# I need resolve this menu dropdown issue

Tags: javascript, html, list, menu, dropdown

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\gyld2\Documents\dropdown menu\dropdown.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\gyld2\Documents\dropdown menu\dropdown.js"></script>
  <button id="btn">Click Here</button>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const button = document.getElementById("btn");

const list = document.getElementById("list");

list.style.display = "none";

button.addEventListener("click",(event)=> {
  if (list.style.display == "none") {

    list.style.display = "block";

    else {

          list.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
})
```

[how my menu looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n0kv.png)

and i want it to be something like this:

[how it is when it's closed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxZ9b.png)

[how it is when it's opened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dxu5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Typo Error

```
if (list.style.display == "none") {
   list.style.display = "block";
 }
else {
  list.style.display = "none";
}
```

```js
const button = document.getElementById("btn");

const list = document.getElementById("list");

list.style.display = "none";

button.addEventListener("click",(event)=> {
  if (list.style.display == "none") {
      list.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
      list.style.display = "none";
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <button id="btn">Click Here</button>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```